# Algorithm - Generate position X and Y base on distance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, algorithm

Let's say I have a schema locations

```
{
  x : 0,
  y : 0
},
{
  x : 2,
  y : 1
},

{
  x : -1,
  y : -2
},
```

Requirement :

- New location must nearest to X = 0 , Y = 0
- New location must be different 2 in X or Y and difference 1 in other. Exp : I have location {x : 0, y: 0}, new location has to be {x : 2, y : 1} or {x : -2, y : 1} or {x 1: y: 2} and so on

Distance calculate by Pythagorean theorem

Distance from X: 0, Y: 0 to X1: 1, Y1: 1

```
Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y - y1, 2))
```

Please recommend for me an algorithm to do this. Looping through all locations to calculate distance is the last thing I am thinking about.

I am using Mongoose and NodeJS.

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a mathematical, rather than a MongoDB, question. But for that it is not sufficiently precise: How is the distance between two locations calculated, for example? And does "next to" mean "difference 1 in X or Y while the other coordinate is the same"?

Comment: Hi, I updated my question. The pythagorean theorem is used to calculate distance, new location has to difference of 1 in X  and Y with nearest location

Comment: Sorry, New location must be difference 2 in X or Y and difference 1 for other

Comment: I really don't get your problem. It seems the only valid new locations are the ones where one coordinate is `+/- 2` and the other is `+/- 1`. And all of them are equidistant to `(0, 0)` ...